# Privacy protection while sharing an AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, privacy, privacy-protection

I am thinking of getting an AWS account for hosting some hobby bots of mine. I have an online collaborater also in my hobby - we don't know each other personally not even our real names. Mainly because we met each other in a political forum though our hobby in unrelated to politics. If I get a paid AWS account using my credit card, would I be able to create a separate login credential for him on my account such that no personal info of mine would be visible to him - like credit card number or name etc?

Comment: Amazon web service questions are on topic here only if the question is about the operating system or using a PC application hosted there.

Comment: @Mokubai - my question had a running bounty. Was my bounty credited back - i am not sure how to check?

Comment: @Mokubai - also do you know which stackexchange site would this question be appropriate for?

Comment: Your bounty does appear to have been refunded. No I don't know where this might be appropriate.  Not all topics have a site at Stack Exchange. Maybe [webapps.se] but your question is more about the backend and company billing than it is actually using their webapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. AWS has an Identity and Access Management (IAM) system that allows you to give him limited web and/or programmatic access to AWS resources.

Once you have created the AWS account you'll have what is called a root user. Give that user a complex password and protect it with multi-factor authentication (MFA). The root user should not be used for day-to-day operations.

For that you open the IAM section and create a new user for yourself. You can then assign that user roles and policies that grant it the capabilities you need.

Finally, you do the same for your collaborator. Make sure to only give his account the permissions that he really needs. Send him the AWS console link (the login page), username and password (and if programmatic access is required the access key id and access key secret).

Here's how it looks like when you try to access the payment section without having the required permissions:

[image: aws-billing-access-denied-msg]

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Looks like the mods have closed the question as off-topic - I have another question also but they closed that also - in the free tier, is it possible to change some settings where by your account gets locked rather than your credit card being charged if you cross the free tier limits

Comment: If I give the user sudo permissions would that allow him to access billing info?

Comment: There's no built-in way to prevent your card from being charged when you exceed free limits as far as I know. Also the IAM roles and permissions are really fine grained. By default only the account owner (root user) can access the billing information: see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/control-access-billing.html